Is it ok to repost my month-old unanswered question about a PS5 controller from Super User?
One month ago I wrote a question about how my PC wouldn't go to sleep if a PS5 controller was plugged in. At the time I debated whether I should post it to Super User, a community of PC enthusiasts, or Arqade, a community of gamers. At the time I posted to Super User. One month later, that question has gotten no answers, even after putting up a bounty.
I'd like to attempt to ask the question on Arqade in hopes of getting an answer. However, I know cross posting is generally discouraged. I have considered a few options:

Deleting my post on Super User and re-asking on Arqade
Re-asking the question on Arqade and linking back to the original question on Super User
Asking a Super User moderator to migrate my question to Arqade

What would be the best course of action? Would it be acceptable to repost or transfer the question to Arqade?

I'd say the rule about cross-posting is more to stop people from just spamming their question across multiple related sites, without taking the time to engage in a positive manner with a single site.
You've done your due diligence: engaging with commenters, editing for clarifications & supplying relevant information, even offering a bounty, to no avail. So I have no issues with the question being cross-posted.
From a topic standpoint, some users may take issue with this being a more PC troubleshooting question. Personally I think it's ok, if we allow "How can I get my controller working on PC?", we should also allow "How can I get my controller to STOP working on PC??" But I can't guarantee everyone thinks the same.

If I did crosspost, would it be appropriate to leave a comment linking the original question on Super User?

I think that's fine

Question has been posted.
